# Exclude a user role from LoginView/RoleGroup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there a way to exclude a Role using the LoginView RoleGroup control combination. My problem is that a user is in both customer and trialUser roles. I want to display a menu option only for customer roles, not for trial user. If I say the following, it will display the option for both trial and customer role users since the trial user is also a customer. I want the "Link" to appear only for customers so basically I have to say include "customer" but exclude "trial".

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView4" runat="server">
                        <RoleGroups>
                            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Customer">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <li>Link</li>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:RoleGroup>
                        </RoleGroups>
                    </asp:LoginView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it turned out to be simple. It seems like the role group will match the first role it finds and then skip the rest. So, this did the trick.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView4" runat="server">
                        <RoleGroups>
                            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Trial">
                                <ContentTemplate>                                   
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:RoleGroup>
                            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Customer">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <li>Link</li>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:RoleGroup>
                        </RoleGroups>
                    </asp:LoginView>
```